# Magento2: Can't access less variables from another file

Tags: magento2, theme

Current File Structure:

```
web
|-css
   |-custom-variables.less
   |-header.less
   |-main.less
```

In `header.less`

```
a{
    color: @primary-color;
}
```

In `custom-variables.less`

```
@primary-color: #004e99;
```

In `main.less`

```
@import 'custom-variables';
@import 'header';
```

When I compile the Less files using Grunt, it is working properly. But when I switch to `production` mode or use `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`, I get this error:

```
[Magento\Framework\View\Asset\ContentProcessorException]                     
  Compilation from source:                                                     
  frontend/Custom/Theme/en_AU/css/header.less                           
  variable @primary-color is undefined in file ..../var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/Custom/Theme/en_AU/css/header.less in header.less on line 10, column 10                              
  08|   }                                                                       
  09|   a{                                                                      
  10|       color: @primary-color;                                                 
  11|   }                                                                       
  12| }
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or there another way of importing less variables from another file?

Comment: You tried to change the order of files `@import 'header'; @import 'custom-variables'; `.

Comment: No, I get the same error.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I am experiencing the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I just found the answer.

**Create partial files**

The files that are imported in `main.less` should be renamed as:

```
web
|-css
    |-_custom-variables.less
    |-_header.less
    |-main.less
```

After learning SASS, I found about `partials` files (files that don't need to be separate `css` file but just be imported - [link to Sass guide](http://sass-lang.com/guide)).

When I looked into the documentation at [lesscss.org](http://lesscss.org), I couldn't find anything related. So I just tested this out by renaming those files and adding an underscore(_) to the beginning and it works!!

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

If your theme inherited from **Blank** or **Luma**, You can use default way to define or redefine variables.

To add custom variables use `<Package>/<Theme>/web/css/source/_variables.less`, to redefine UI library variables use `<Package>/<Theme>/web/css/source/_theme.less` or `<Package>/<Theme>/web/css/source/lib/_<component>.less`.

This files are included by default. It means that You don't need to use `@import` in your `main.less`.